# finding common prefix of array of strings

Tags: php, string, algorithm, prefix

I have an array like this:

```
$sports = array(
'Softball - Counties',
'Softball - Eastern',
'Softball - North Harbour',
'Softball - South',
'Softball - Western'
);
```

I would like to find the longest common prefix of the string. In this instance, it would be `'Softball - '`

I am thinking that I would follow this process

```
$i = 1;

// loop to the length of the first string
while ($i < strlen($sports[0]) {

  // grab the left most part up to i in length
  $match = substr($sports[0], 0, $i);

  // loop through all the values in array, and compare if they match
  foreach ($sports as $sport) {

     if ($match != substr($sport, 0, $i) {
         // didn't match, return the part that did match
         return substr($sport, 0, $i-1);
     }

  } // foreach

   // increase string length
   $i++;
} // while

// if you got to here, then all of them must be identical
```

Questions

1. Is there a built-in function or a much simpler way of doing this?
2. For my 5 lines array that is probably fine, but **if I were to do several thousand lines arrays**, there would be a lot of overhead, so I would have to be move calculated with my starting values of `$i`, eg `$i` = halfway of string, if it fails, then `$i/2` until it works, then increment `$i` by 1 until we succeed. So that we are doing the least number of comparisons to get a result.

Is there a formula/algorithm out already out there for this kind of problem?

Comment: Are you looking for the longest common prefix, or substring? E.g. if you have a_abli and a_cable, should the answer be "a_" or "abl"?

Comment: the prefix, i have amended the title to be more specific

Comment: if you *an have array like this*, why don't you just explode each item and grab a first element?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250514/find-length-of-initial-segment-matching-mask-on-arrays

Comment: @silentghost, re explode, it is user editable data, so it could vary a lot from the example i gave

Comment: @bumperbox: if so, what are you going to do with spelling errors?

Comment: @silentghost, i will live with spelling mistakes, they can always go back and fix them up if there is a problem.

Comment: This is a relarively poor [mcve] because the "prefix" also happens to end on the space after the first occurring hyphen.  Is the common hyphen a coincidence or a reliable marker for identifying the "prefix"? The input strings are too similar to be useful in identifying correct/incorrect solutions.  @bumper

Comment: @mickmackusa those are real life values. I suggest to users to put a hyphen where they want the split to occur, but not everyone gets it right, as it was a free text field. There are probably better ways to do this in the UX, but those changes were outside the scope of the project at the time.

Comment: @bump I'd like to answer this one.  Can you perhaps improve the question by offering sample that is more diverse and will make the output more indicative of the desired logic? (Everything is `softball - ` at the moment.)  So are hyphens not being respected at all in the logic? What if the first few characters after the `-` are a match?  If you had `Softball - Central`, is `Softball - C` the longest match?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because its requirements are unclear and the [mcve] is insufficient in portraying the variability and intricacies of the task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I implemented @diogoriba algorithm into code, with this result:

- Finding the common prefix of the first two strings, and then comparing this with all following strings starting from the 3rd, and trim the common string if nothing common is found, wins in situations where there is more in common in the prefixes than different.
- But bumperbox's original algorithm (except the bugfixes) wins where the strings have less in common in their prefix than different. *Details in the code comments!*

Another idea I implemented:

First check for the shortest string in the array, and use this for comparison rather than simply the first string. *In the code, this is implemented with the custom written function arrayStrLenMin().*

- Can bring down iterations dramatically, but the function arrayStrLenMin() may itself cause ( more or less) iterations.
- Simply starting with the length of first string in array seems quite clumsy, but may turn out effective, if arrayStrLenMin() needs many iterations.

### Get the maximum common prefix of strings in an array with as little iterations as possible (PHP)

**Code + Extensive Testing + Remarks:**

```
function arrayStrLenMin ($arr, $strictMode = false, $forLoop = false) {
    $errArrZeroLength = -1; // Return value for error: Array is empty
    $errOtherType = -2;     // Return value for error: Found other type (than string in array)
    $errStrNone = -3;       // Return value for error: No strings found (in array)

    $arrLength = count($arr);
    if ($arrLength <= 0 ) { return $errArrZeroLength; }
    $cur = 0;

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_string($val)) {
            $min = strlen($val);
            $strFirstFound = $key;
            // echo("Key\tLength / Notification / Error\n");
            // echo("$key\tFound first string member at key with length: $min!\n");
            break;
        }
        else if ($strictMode) { return $errOtherType; } // At least 1 type other than string was found.
    }
    if (! isset($min)) { return $errStrNone; } // No string was found in array.

    // SpeedRatio of foreach/for is approximately 2/1 as dicussed at:
    // http://juliusbeckmann.de/blog/php-foreach-vs-while-vs-for-the-loop-battle.html

    // If $strFirstFound is found within the first 1/SpeedRatio (=0.5) of the array, "foreach" is faster!

    if (! $forLoop) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
            if (is_string($val)) {
                $cur = strlen($val);
                // echo("$key\t$cur\n");
                if ($cur == 0) { return $cur; } // 0 is the shortest possible string, so we can abort here.
                if ($cur < $min) { $min = $cur; }
            }
        // else { echo("$key\tNo string!\n"); }
        }
    }

    // If $strFirstFound is found after the first 1/SpeedRatio (=0.5) of the array, "for" is faster!

    else {
        for ($i = $strFirstFound + 1; $i < $arrLength; $i++) {
            if (is_string($arr[$i])) {
                $cur = strlen($arr[$i]);
                // echo("$i\t$cur\n");
                if ($cur == 0) { return $cur; } // 0 is the shortest possible string, so we can abort here.
                if ($cur < $min) { $min = $cur; }
            }
            // else { echo("$i\tNo string!\n"); }
        }
    }

    return $min;
}

function strCommonPrefixByStr($arr, $strFindShortestFirst = false) {
    $arrLength = count($arr);
    if ($arrLength < 2) { return false; }

    // Determine loop length
    /// Find shortest string in array: Can bring down iterations dramatically, but the function arrayStrLenMin() itself can cause ( more or less) iterations.
    if ($strFindShortestFirst) { $end = arrayStrLenMin($arr, true); }
    /// Simply start with length of first string in array: Seems quite clumsy, but may turn out effective, if arrayStrLenMin() needs many iterations.
    else { $end = strlen($arr[0]); }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $end + 1; $i++) {
        // Grab the part from 0 up to $i
        $commonStrMax = substr($arr[0], 0, $i);
        echo("Match: $i\t$commonStrMax\n");
        // Loop through all the values in array, and compare if they match
        foreach ($arr as $key => $str) {
            echo("  Str: $key\t$str\n");
            // Didn't match, return the part that did match
            if ($commonStrMax != substr($str, 0, $i)) {
                    return substr($commonStrMax, 0, $i-1);
            }
        }
    }
    // Special case: No mismatch (hence no return) happened until loop end!
    return $commonStrMax; // Thus entire first common string is the common prefix!
}

function strCommonPrefixByChar($arr, $strFindShortestFirst = false) {
    $arrLength = count($arr);
    if ($arrLength < 2) { return false; }

    // Determine loop length
    /// Find shortest string in array: Can bring down iterations dramatically, but the function arrayStrLenMin() itself can cause ( more or less) iterations.
    if ($strFindShortestFirst) { $end = arrayStrLenMin($arr, true); }
    /// Simply start with length of first string in array: Seems quite clumsy, but may turn out effective, if arrayStrLenMin() needs many iterations.
    else { $end = strlen($arr[0]); }

    for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $end + 1; $i++) {
        // Grab char $i
        $char = substr($arr[0], $i, 1);
        echo("Match: $i\t"); echo(str_pad($char, $i+1, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT)); echo("\n");
        // Loop through all the values in array, and compare if they match
        foreach ($arr as $key => $str) {
            echo("  Str: $key\t$str\n");
            // Didn't match, return the part that did match
            if ($char != $str[$i]) { // Same functionality as ($char != substr($str, $i, 1)). Same efficiency?
                    return substr($arr[0], 0, $i);
            }
        }
    }
    // Special case: No mismatch (hence no return) happened until loop end!
    return substr($arr[0], 0, $end); // Thus entire first common string is the common prefix!
}


function strCommonPrefixByNeighbour($arr) {
    $arrLength = count($arr);
    if ($arrLength < 2) { return false; }

    /// Get the common string prefix of the first 2 strings
    $strCommonMax = strCommonPrefixByChar(array($arr[0], $arr[1]));
    if ($strCommonMax === false) { return false; }
    if ($strCommonMax == "") { return ""; }
    $strCommonMaxLength = strlen($strCommonMax);

    /// Now start looping from the 3rd string
    echo("-----\n");
    for ($i = 2; ($i < $arrLength) && ($strCommonMaxLength >= 1); $i++ ) {
        echo("  STR: $i\t{$arr[$i]}\n");

        /// Compare the maximum common string with the next neighbour

        /*
        //// Compare by char: Method unsuitable!

        // Iterate from string end to string beginning
        for ($ii = $strCommonMaxLength - 1; $ii >= 0; $ii--) {
            echo("Match: $ii\t"); echo(str_pad($arr[$i][$ii], $ii+1, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT)); echo("\n");
            // If you find the first mismatch from the end, break.
            if ($arr[$i][$ii] != $strCommonMax[$ii]) {
                $strCommonMaxLength = $ii - 1; break;
                // BUT!!! We may falsely assume that the string from the first mismatch until the begining match! This new string neighbour string is completely "unexplored land", there might be differing chars closer to the beginning. This method is not suitable. Better use string comparison than char comparison.
            }
        }
        */

        //// Compare by string

        for ($ii = $strCommonMaxLength; $ii > 0; $ii--) {
            echo("MATCH: $ii\t$strCommonMax\n");
            if (substr($arr[$i],0,$ii) == $strCommonMax) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                $strCommonMax = substr($strCommonMax,0,$ii - 1);
                $strCommonMaxLength--;
            }
        }
    }
    return substr($arr[0], 0, $strCommonMaxLength);
}





// Tests for finding the common prefix

/// Scenarios

$filesLeastInCommon = array (
"/Vol/1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/a/1",
"/Vol/2/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/a/2",
"/Vol/1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/b/1",
"/Vol/1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/b/2",
"/Vol/2/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/b/c/1",
"/Vol/2/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/a/1",
);

$filesLessInCommon = array (
"/Vol/1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/a/1",
"/Vol/1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/a/2",
"/Vol/1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/b/1",
"/Vol/1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/b/2",
"/Vol/2/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/b/c/1",
"/Vol/2/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/a/1",
);

$filesMoreInCommon = array (
"/Voluuuuuuuuuuuuuumes/1/a/a/1",
"/Voluuuuuuuuuuuuuumes/1/a/a/2",
"/Voluuuuuuuuuuuuuumes/1/a/b/1",
"/Voluuuuuuuuuuuuuumes/1/a/b/2",
"/Voluuuuuuuuuuuuuumes/2/a/b/c/1",
"/Voluuuuuuuuuuuuuumes/2/a/a/1",
);

$sameDir = array (
"/Volumes/1/a/a/",
"/Volumes/1/a/a/aaaaa/2",
);

$sameFile = array (
"/Volumes/1/a/a/1",
"/Volumes/1/a/a/1",
);

$noCommonPrefix = array (
"/Volumes/1/a/a/",
"/Volumes/1/a/a/aaaaa/2",
"Net/1/a/a/aaaaa/2",
);

$longestLast = array (
"/Volumes/1/a/a/1",
"/Volumes/1/a/a/aaaaa/2",
);

$longestFirst = array (
"/Volumes/1/a/a/aaaaa/1",
"/Volumes/1/a/a/2",
);

$one = array ("/Volumes/1/a/a/aaaaa/1");

$empty = array ( );


// Test Results for finding  the common prefix

/*

I tested my functions in many possible scenarios.
The results, the common prefixes, were always correct in all scenarios!
Just try a function call with your individual array!

Considering iteration efficiency, I also performed tests:

I put echo functions into the functions where iterations occur, and measured the number of CLI line output via:
php <script with strCommonPrefixByStr or strCommonPrefixByChar> | egrep "^  Str:" | wc -l   GIVES TOTAL ITERATION SUM.
php <Script with strCommonPrefixByNeighbour> | egrep "^  Str:" | wc -l   PLUS   | egrep "^MATCH:" | wc -l   GIVES TOTAL ITERATION SUM.

My hypothesis was proven:
strCommonPrefixByChar wins in situations where the strings have less in common in their beginning (=prefix).
strCommonPrefixByNeighbour wins where there is more in common in the prefixes.

*/

// Test Results Table
// Used Functions | Iteration amount | Remarks

// $result = (strCommonPrefixByStr($filesLessInCommon)); // 35
// $result = (strCommonPrefixByChar($filesLessInCommon)); // 35 // Same amount of iterations, but much fewer characters compared because ByChar instead of ByString!
// $result = (strCommonPrefixByNeighbour($filesLessInCommon)); // 88 + 42 = 130 // Loses in this category!

// $result = (strCommonPrefixByStr($filesMoreInCommon)); // 137
// $result = (strCommonPrefixByChar($filesMoreInCommon)); // 137 // Same amount of iterations, but much fewer characters compared because ByChar instead of ByString!
// $result = (strCommonPrefixByNeighbour($filesLeastInCommon)); // 12 + 4 = 16 // Far the winner in this category!

echo("Common prefix of all members:\n");
var_dump($result);





// Tests for finding the shortest string in array

/// Arrays

// $empty = array ();
// $noStrings = array (0,1,2,3.0001,4,false,true,77);
// $stringsOnly = array ("one","two","three","four");
// $mixed = array (0,1,2,3.0001,"four",false,true,"seven", 8888);

/// Scenarios

// I list them from fewest to most iterations, which is not necessarily equivalent to slowest to fastest!
// For speed consider the remarks in the code considering the Speed ratio of foreach/for!

//// Fewest iterations (immediate abort on "Found other type", use "for" loop)

// foreach( array($empty, $noStrings, $stringsOnly, $mixed) as $arr) {
//  echo("NEW ANALYSIS:\n");
//  echo("Result: " . arrayStrLenMin($arr, true, true) . "\n\n");
// }

/* Results:

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: Array is empty!

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: Found other type!

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Key Length / Notification / Error
    0   Found first string member at key with length: 3!
    1   3
    2   5
    3   4
    Result: 3

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: Found other type!

*/

//// Fewer iterations (immediate abort on "Found other type", use "foreach" loop)

// foreach( array($empty, $noStrings, $stringsOnly, $mixed) as $arr) {
//  echo("NEW ANALYSIS:\n");
//  echo("Result: " . arrayStrLenMin($arr, true, false) . "\n\n");
// }

/* Results:

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: Array is empty!

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: Found other type!

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Key Length / Notification / Error
    0   Found first string member at key with length: 3!
    0   3
    1   3
    2   5
    3   4
    Result: 3

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: Found other type!

*/

//// More iterations (No immediate abort on "Found other type", use "for" loop)

// foreach( array($empty, $noStrings, $stringsOnly, $mixed) as $arr) {
//  echo("NEW ANALYSIS:\n");
//  echo("Result: " . arrayStrLenMin($arr, false, true) . "\n\n");
// }

/* Results:

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: Array is empty!

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: No strings found!

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Key Length / Notification / Error
    0   Found first string member at key with length: 3!
    1   3
    2   5
    3   4
    Result: 3

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Key Length / Notification / Error
    4   Found first string member at key with length: 4!
    5   No string!
    6   No string!
    7   5
    8   No string!
    Result: 4

*/


//// Most iterations (No immediate abort on "Found other type", use "foreach" loop)

// foreach( array($empty, $noStrings, $stringsOnly, $mixed) as $arr) {
//  echo("NEW ANALYSIS:\n");
//  echo("Result: " . arrayStrLenMin($arr, false, false) . "\n\n");
// }

/* Results:

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: Array is empty!

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Result: No strings found!

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Key Length / Notification / Error
    0   Found first string member at key with length: 3!
    0   3
    1   3
    2   5
    3   4
    Result: 3

    NEW ANALYSIS:
    Key Length / Notification / Error
    4   Found first string member at key with length: 4!
    0   No string!
    1   No string!
    2   No string!
    3   No string!
    4   4
    5   No string!
    6   No string!
    7   5
    8   No string!
    Result: 4

*/
```

Comment: Gumbo's answer is much simpler. Can you demonstrate that this answer is significantly faster?

Comment: See Gustav Bertram's more recent answer (currently far below), which avoids all this, by first *sorting* the list of strings. This has the benefit that you can leverage an already existing, optimized, sort method. So can easily implement a simple solution, without needing to expend effort optimizing!

Answer (score 18):

If you can sort your array, then there is a simple and very fast solution.

Simply compare the first item to the last one.

If the strings are sorted, any prefix common to all strings will be common to the sorted first and last strings.

```php
sort($sport);

$s1 = $sport[0];               // First string
$s2 = $sport[count($sport)-1]; // Last string
$len = min(strlen($s1), strlen($s2));

// While we still have string to compare,
// if the indexed character is the same in both strings,
// increment the index. 
for ($i=0; $i<$len && $s1[$i]==$s2[$i]; $i++); 

$prefix = substr($s1, 0, $i);
```

Comment: Brilliant; uses already optimized sort algorithm, so don't need to expend effort optimizing this special code.

Comment: Looks like this is just comparing two strings, not a whole list of strings.... Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer Sorting the strings orders them, so any prefix that is common to all strings, will also be common to the first and last strings. Thus we only need to compare the first and last strings to determine the common prefix.

Answer (score 15):

I would use this:

```
$prefix = array_shift($array);  // take the first item as initial prefix
$length = strlen($prefix);
// compare the current prefix with the prefix of the same length of the other items
foreach ($array as $item) {
    // check if there is a match; if not, decrease the prefix by one character at a time
    while ($length && substr($item, 0, $length) !== $prefix) {
        $length--;
        $prefix = substr($prefix, 0, -1);
    }
    if (!$length) {
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**  
Here’s another solution, iteratively comparing each n-th character of the strings until a mismatch is found:

```
$pl = 0; // common prefix length
$n = count($array);
$l = strlen($array[0]);
while ($pl < $l) {
    $c = $array[0][$pl];
    for ($i=1; $i<$n; $i++) {
        if ($array[$i][$pl] !== $c) break 2;
    }
    $pl++;
}
$prefix = substr($array[0], 0, $pl);
```

This is even more efficient as there are only at most *numberOfStrings*‍·‍*commonPrefixLength* atomic comparisons.

Comment: I suspect the second solution is LESS efficient in OP's test case, given many strings, because it is building up the prefix one character at a time, testing ALL strings during that time. So it will ALWAYS do numberOfStrings x commonPrefixLength comparisons.  Whereas the first solution can quickly eliminate most of the prefix, just comparing the first two strings.

Comment: Even better (for some data) would be two loops. The first loop starts from zero, but only examines the first two strings, one character at a time. This gives an "upper bound" on the possible size. Then do the first solution for the remainder of the strings, decreasing the prefix. For the test data shown, the cost is `N + L` instead of `N * L`.

Answer (score 7):

Probably there is some terribly well-regarded algorithm for this, but just off the top of my head, if you know your commonality is going to be on the left-hand side like in your example, you could do way better than your posted methodology by first finding the commonality of the first two strings, and then iterating down the rest of the list, trimming the common string as necessary to achieve commonality or terminating with failure if you trim all the way to nothing.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're on the right way. But instead of incrementing i when all of the string passes, you could do this:

1) Compare the first 2 strings in the array and find out how many common characters they have. Save the common characters in a separate string called maxCommon, for example.

2) Compare the third string w/ maxCommon. If the number of common characters is smaller, trim maxCommon to the characters that match.

3) Repeat and rinse for the rest of the array. At the end of the process, maxCommon will have the string that is common to all of the array elements.

This will add some overhead because you'll need to compare each string w/ maxCommon, but will drastically reduce the number of iterations you'll need to get your results.

Comment: +1 Exactly how I would have done it. Another advantage: once you get to a string with a different first character, you can stop iterating through the remaining strings, as there is no common prefix.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by "common part" you mean "longest common prefix". That is a much simpler to compute than any common substring.

This cannot be done without reading `(n+1) * m` characters in the worst case and `n * m + 1` in the best case, where `n` is the length of the longest common prefix and `m` is the number of strings.

Comparing one letter at a time achieves that efficiency (Big Theta (n * m)).

Your proposed algorithm runs in Big Theta(n^2 * m), which is much, much slower for large inputs.

The third proposed algorithm of finding the longest prefix of the first two strings, then comparing that with the third, fourth, etc. also has a running time in Big Theta(n * m), but with a higher constant factor. It will probably only be slightly slower in practice.

Overall, I would recommend just rolling your own function, since the first algorithm is too slow and the two others will be about equally complicated to write anyway.

Check out [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations) for a description of Big Theta notation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an elegant, recursive implementation in JavaScript:

```
function prefix(strings) {
    switch (strings.length) {

      case 0:
        return "";

      case 1:
        return strings[0];

      case 2:
        // compute the prefix between the two strings
        var a = strings[0],
            b = strings[1],
            n = Math.min(a.length, b.length),
            i = 0;
        while (i < n && a.charAt(i) === b.charAt(i))
            ++i;
        return a.substring(0, i);

      default:
        // return the common prefix of the first string,
        // and the common prefix of the rest of the strings
        return prefix([ strings[0], prefix(strings.slice(1)) ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. not that I know of
2. yes: instead of comparing the substring from 0 to length i, you can simply check the ith character (you already know that characters 0 to i-1 match).

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet version, perhaps not the most efficient:

```
/// Return length of longest common prefix in an array of strings.
function _commonPrefix($array) {
    if(count($array) < 2) {
        if(count($array) == 0)
            return false; // empty array: undefined prefix
        else
            return strlen($array[0]); // 1 element: trivial case
    }
    $len = max(array_map('strlen',$array)); // initial upper limit: max length of all strings.
    $prevval = reset($array);
    while(($newval = next($array)) !== FALSE) {
        for($j = 0 ; $j < $len ; $j += 1)
            if($newval[$j] != $prevval[$j])
                $len = $j;
        $prevval = $newval;
    }
    return $len;
}

// TEST CASE:
$arr = array('/var/yam/yamyam/','/var/yam/bloorg','/var/yar/sdoo');
print_r($arr);
$plen = _commonprefix($arr);
$pstr = substr($arr[0],0,$plen);
echo "Res: $plen\n";
echo "==> ".$pstr."\n";
echo "dir: ".dirname($pstr.'aaaa')."\n";
```

Output of the test case:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /var/yam/yamyam/
    [1] => /var/yam/bloorg
    [2] => /var/yar/sdoo
)
Res: 7
==> /var/ya
dir: /var
```

Answer (score 0):

**@bumperbox**

1. Your basic code needed some correction to work in ALL scenarios!

   - Your loop only compares until one character before the last character!
   - The mismatch can possibly occur 1 loop cycle after the latest common character.
   - Hence you have to at least check until 1 character after your first string's last character.
   - Hence your comparison operator must be "<= 1" or "< 2".
2. Currently your algorithm fails

   - if the first string is completely included in all other strings,
   - or completely included in all other strings except the last character.

In my next answer/post, I will attach iteration optimized code!

**Original Bumperbox code PLUS correction (PHP):**

```
function shortest($sports) {
 $i = 1;

 // loop to the length of the first string
 while ($i < strlen($sports[0])) {

  // grab the left most part up to i in length
  // REMARK: Culturally biased towards LTR writing systems. Better say: Grab frombeginning...
  $match = substr($sports[0], 0, $i);

  // loop through all the values in array, and compare if they match
  foreach ($sports as $sport) {
   if ($match != substr($sport, 0, $i)) {
    // didn't match, return the part that did match
    return substr($sport, 0, $i-1);
   }
  }
 $i++; // increase string length
 }
}

function shortestCorrect($sports) {
 $i = 1;
 while ($i <= strlen($sports[0]) + 1) {
  // Grab the string from its beginning with length $i
  $match = substr($sports[0], 0, $i);
  foreach ($sports as $sport) {
   if ($match != substr($sport, 0, $i)) {
    return substr($sport, 0, $i-1);
   }
  }
  $i++;
 }
 // Special case: No mismatch happened until loop end! Thus entire str1 is common prefix!
 return $sports[0];
}

$sports1 = array(
'Softball',
'Softball - Eastern',
'Softball - North Harbour');

$sports2 = array(
'Softball - Wester',
'Softball - Western',
);

$sports3 = array(
'Softball - Western',
'Softball - Western',
);

$sports4 = array(
'Softball - Westerner',
'Softball - Western',
);

echo("Output of the original function:\n"); // Failure scenarios

var_dump(shortest($sports1)); // NULL rather than the correct 'Softball'
var_dump(shortest($sports2)); // NULL rather than the correct 'Softball - Wester'
var_dump(shortest($sports3)); // NULL rather than the correct 'Softball - Western'
var_dump(shortest($sports4)); // Only works if the second string is at least one character longer!

echo("\nOutput of the corrected function:\n"); // All scenarios work
var_dump(shortestCorrect($sports1));
var_dump(shortestCorrect($sports2));
var_dump(shortestCorrect($sports3));
var_dump(shortestCorrect($sports4));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  It can be further optimised by not having to check the lengths of the strings if we can use the null terminating character (but I am assuming python strings have length cached somewhere?)

```
def find_common_prefix_len(strings):
    """
    Given a list of strings, finds the length common prefix in all of them.
    So
    apple
    applet
    application
    would return 3
    """
    prefix          = 0
    curr_index      = -1
    num_strings     = len(strings)
    string_lengths  = [len(s) for s in strings]
    while True:
        curr_index  += 1
        ch_in_si    = None
        for si in xrange(0, num_strings):
            if curr_index >= string_lengths[si]:
                return prefix
            else:
                if si == 0:
                    ch_in_si = strings[0][curr_index]
                elif strings[si][curr_index] != ch_in_si:
                    return prefix
        prefix += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive algorithm like this:

1 - get the first string in the array
2 - call the recursive prefix method with the first string as a param
3 - if prefix is empty return no prefix
4 - loop through all the strings in the array
4.1 - if any of the strings does not start with the prefix
4.1.1 - call recursive prefix method with prefix - 1 as a param
4.2 return prefix

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Common prefix
    $common = '';

    $sports = array(
    'Softball T - Counties',
    'Softball T - Eastern',
    'Softball T - North Harbour',
    'Softball T - South',
    'Softball T - Western'
    );

    // find mini string
    $minLen = strlen($sports[0]);
    foreach ($sports as $s){
        if($minLen > strlen($s))
            $minLen = strlen($s);
    }


    // flag to break out of inner loop
    $flag = false;

    // The possible common string length does not exceed the minimum string length.
    // The following solution is O(n^2), this can be improve.
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $minLen; $i++){
        $tmp = $sports[0][$i];

        foreach ($sports as $s){
            if($s[$i] != $tmp)
                $flag = true;
        }
        if($flag)
            break;
        else
            $common .= $sports[0][$i];
    }

    print $common;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions here work only for finding commonalities at the beginning of strings. Here is a function that looks for the longest common substring *anywhere* in an array of strings.

http://www.christopherbloom.com/2011/02/24/find-the-longest-common-substring-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

The top answer seemed a bit long, so here's a concise solution with a runtime of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```
function findLongestPrefix($arr) {
  return array_reduce($arr, function($prefix, $item) {
    $length = min(strlen($prefix), strlen($item));
    while (substr($prefix, 0, $length) !== substr($item, 0, $length)) {
      $length--;
    }
    return substr($prefix, 0, $length);
  }, $arr[0]);
}

print findLongestPrefix($sports); // Softball -
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's another alternative I came up with.

I used this for finding the common prefix for a list of products codes (ie. where there are multiple product SKUs that have a common series of characters at the start):

```
/**
 * Try to find a common prefix for a list of strings
 * 
 * @param array $strings
 * @return string
 */
function findCommonPrefix(array $strings)
{
    $prefix = '';
    $chars = array_map("str_split", $strings);
    $matches = call_user_func_array("array_intersect_assoc", $chars);
    if ($matches) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != $i) {
                unset($matches[$key]);
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $prefix = join('', $matches);
    }

    return $prefix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to the @Gumbo answer. If you want to ensure that the chosen, common prefix does not break words, use this. I am just having it look for a blank space at the end of the chosen string. If that exists we know that there was more to all of the phrases, so we truncate it.

```
function product_name_intersection($array){

    $pl = 0; // common prefix length
    $n = count($array);
    $l = strlen($array[0]);
    $first = current($array);

    while ($pl < $l) {
        $c = $array[0][$pl];
        for ($i=1; $i<$n; $i++) {
            if (!isset($array[$i][$pl]) || $array[$i][$pl] !== $c) break 2;
        }
        $pl++;
    }
    $prefix = substr($array[0], 0, $pl);

    if ($pl < strlen($first) && substr($prefix, -1, 1) != ' ') {

        $prefix = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $prefix);
    }

    $prefix =  preg_replace('/^\W*(.+?)\W*$/', '$1', $prefix);

    return $prefix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a Typescript solution for this question. I split it into 2 methods, just to keep it clean while at it.

```
function longestCommonPrefix(strs: string[]): string {
    let output = '';
    if(strs.length > 0) {
        output = strs[0];
        if(strs.length > 1) {
            for(let i=1; i <strs.length; i++) {
                output = checkCommonPrefix(output, strs[i]);
            }
        }
    }  
    return output;
};
    
function checkCommonPrefix(str1: string, str2: string): string {
    let output = '';
    let len = Math.min(str1.length, str2.length);
    let i = 0;
    while(i < len) {
        if(str1[i] === str2[i]) {
            output += str1[i];
        } else {
            i = len;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*("if I were to do several thousand lines arrays")*

The data structure for this is a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (Prefix Tree): A tree-like data structure used to store a dynamic set of strings where each node represents a single character.

- Time Efficiency: Search, Insertion & Deletion: With a time-complexity of **O(m)** where m is the length of the string.
- Space Efficiency: Store the unique characters present in the strings. This can be a space advantage compared to storing the entire strings.

--

Trie Visualization for your input (Green nodes are marked: endOfString):

[image]

--

PHP implementation:

```php
<?php

class TrieNode 
{
    public $childNode = []; // Associative array to store child nodes
    public $endOfString = false; // Flag to indicate end of a string
}

class Trie 
{
    private $root;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->root = new TrieNode();
    }

    public function insert($string) 
    {
        if (!empty($string)) {
            $this->insertRecursive($this->root, $string);
        }
    }

    private function insertRecursive(&$node, $string) 
    {
        if (empty($string)) {
            $node->endOfString = true;
            return;
        }

        $firstChar = $string[0];
        $remainingString = substr($string, 1);

        if (!isset($node->childNode[$firstChar])) {
            $node->childNode[$firstChar] = new TrieNode();
        }

        $this->insertRecursive($node->childNode[$firstChar], $remainingString);
    }

    public function commonPrefix() 
    {
        $commonPrefix = '';
        $this->commonPrefixRecursive($this->root, $commonPrefix);
        return $commonPrefix;
    }

    private function commonPrefixRecursive($node, &$commonPrefix) 
    {
        if (count($node->childNode) !== 1 || $node->endOfString) {
            return;
        }

        $firstChar = array_key_first($node->childNode);
        $commonPrefix .= $firstChar;
        $this->commonPrefixRecursive($node->childNode[$firstChar], $commonPrefix);
    }
}

// Example usage
$trie = new Trie();
$trie->insert("Softball - Counties");
$trie->insert("Softball - Eastern");
$trie->insert("Softball - North Harbour");
$trie->insert("Softball - South");
$trie->insert("Softball - Western");

echo "Common prefix: " . $trie->commonPrefix() . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Output:

```
Common prefix: Softball -
```

[Demo](https://onecompiler.com/php/428w3k8pe)