# Does an Android package store a developer/company/author name?

Tags: android

I've just been trying out creating a list of applications installed on Android.  I want to do this so I have a list of applications I've installed before I backup and reset my phone to factory settings.

It's going well so far, I have this information:

- package Name
- friendly name
- version number/code
- if its a system package (FLAG_SYSTEM)
- if its a persistent app (FLAG_PERSISTENT)
- and the application description

The last thing that I would like to have but that does not seem to exist is the name of the person/group/company etc that created the application.  That way I can see if I have multiple applications by the same creator.

Is there a specific place this is stored in Android packages or does it just not exist?

I've had a good search around but I can not find anything, but I thought I would try a specific query about it before I give up.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not stored anywhere in your Android package AFAIK.  It's only set by the developer when they register their developer account.

Comment: I had wondered if it might be like that and that information is only displayed in the Market app.  An idea I have for an estimated solution is to look at the package names.  I just found this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250514/find-length-of-initial-segment-matching-mask-on-arrays/1250840#1250840.  Using that on the list of package names is probably the closest I will get to what I want.